# Add a missing key to JSON in a Postgres table via Rails

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to use `update_all` to update any records that is missing a key in a JSON stored in a table cell. `ids` is the ids of those records and I've tried the below...

```
User.where(id: ids).
  update_all(
    "preferences = jsonb_set(preferences, '{some_key}', 'true'"
  )
```

Where the error returns is...

```
Caused by PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"
LINE 1: ...onb_set(preferences, '{some_key}', 'true' WHERE "user...
```

The key takes a string value so not sure why the query is failing.

**UPDATE:**

Based on what was mentioned, I added the parentheses and also added / modified the last two arguments...

```
User.where(id: ids).
  update_all(
    "preferences = jsonb_set(preferences, '{some_key}', 'true'::jsonb, true)"
  )
```

still running into issues and this time it seems related to the key I'm passing

1. I know this key doesn't currently exist for the set of ids
2. I added `true` for `create_missing` so that `1` isn't an issue

I get this error now...

```
Caused by PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function jsonb_set(hstore, unknown, jsonb, boolean) does not exis
```

`some_key` should be a key in `preferences`

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in raw SQL so you are 100% responsible for ensuring that is actually valid SQL. What you have there isn't. Check your parentheses:

```
User.where(id: ids).
update_all(
  "preferences = jsonb_set(preferences, '{some_key}', 'true')"
)
```

If you look more closely at the error message it was telling you there was a problem precisely at the introduction of the `WHERE` clause, and right after `...true'` so that was a good place to look for problems.

Syntax errors like this can be really annoying, but don't forget your database will usually do its best to pin down the place where the problem occurs.

Comment: doh. yeah i just completely missed that...i'll blame the fact that its Friday. thank you!

Comment: I updated it. Still have issues which seems to be due to the key not being available but i thought the `create_missing` parameter would handle it

Comment: That sounds like a different question.

Comment: well not necessarily...it's still the same thing I'm trying to do..just a different error now.

Comment: Different error means different problem. Achieving your objective may require resolving multiple problems.